# Connecting database with hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I know thats a known problem and i made my research but still couldnt find a proper answer and what to do, so my last hope is here. The problem is, when i use phpAdmin i can connect and create my tables in m database. But when i run hibernates connection wizard, after entering the connection properties, if i press the test connection it gives me this error :

```
"Timeout expired. IDE unable to establish connection. Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment.   You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic."
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.11.83.2:3306</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin1s6nbcM</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I m suspecting that there is something wrong with MySQL Java Connector library ;

```
dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

because i get this warning when i build my application:

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for cardsystelefonbuch:cardsystelefonbuch:war:1.0
'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar -> version 5.1.25 vs 5.1.30 @ line 83, column 13

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: First you could try with latest version from maven.

Comment: Actually i tried all different versions but the result is still the same

Comment: Could be firewall blocking connection.

Comment: I also see a version conflict in your maven error log.

Comment: version conflict ? could you give more information pls ?

Comment: 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar -> version 5.1.25 vs 5.1.30 @ line 83, column 13